# Hyper-V internal network, VMs not getting IP from DHCP server?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, dhcp-server

Hyper-V is running in my Win 10 pc, inside there are a Win Srv 2012 R2 and a Win7 vm.
2012 R2 is the main DC, and also DHCP server.

What I want: The VMs to be in a separate network from the host, but also get internet. So basically a private network but with internet.

What I've tried is to set the virtual switch to INTERNAL, and then from the host, share the connection from my physical ethernet to the virtual switch. Then the 2012 uses the IP of this switch as default gateway and it works fine, for this VM, but the W7 Vm DOES NOT get an IP assigned by the 2012.

Now if I change the virtual switch to PRIVATE then everything works as expected in that network.

What am I doing wrong? There is clearly things I'm not understanding.

Thanks!

Comment: Should I have 2 switches one private and one internal and then 2 NICs in the server that would bridge all this together instead?

Host  >(shares)>  VEthernet > NIC1 2012 > NIC2 2012 > VSwitch Private ?

Comment: What results do you get when you run `ipconfig /all` on your Win7 and Windows Server 2012 R2? What is the gateway?